# CPPickerView DataSource

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview, uipickerviewdatasource

Using [CPPickerView](https://github.com/cbpowell/CPPickerView). I have it working and have currently been coding for a bit too long i think and my brain has gone dead so any help would be appreciated. I know the answer is simple but for the life of me i just can't see it.

I want to load an array of strings into the view, not numbers.

The current method to use for numbers is:

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(CPPickerView *)pickerView titleForItem:(NSInteger)item
{
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", item + 1];
}
```

How do i create/edit a method to make strings appear instead of integers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the strings are in an array then perhaps this is what you want:

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(CPPickerView *)pickerView titleForItem:(NSInteger)item {
    return yourStringArray[item];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *someValue = @"Hello";
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", someValue];
```

Comment: Why? Just do: `return someValue;`. Don't needlessly use `stringWithFormat:`.

Comment: I would assume he needs something other than a string constant. I was showing him the `%@` formatting option which allows him to build up what he needs.

Comment: Thanks MattP - yeah i'd tried it this way and was getting issues of %@ returning only open brackets i think maybe because the method required me to use [item]. Thanks heaps!